# Proof of continuously differentiable curve arc length

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation, alternative-proof, curves, arc-length

I was reading [Terence Tao's lecture on complex analysis](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2016/09/27/246a-notes-2-complex-integration/#dash).  This is a question regarding his "continuity" solution to the proposition:

[image: Problem]

---

[image: Proof provided]

---

**My question is: Why is $\Omega_{\varepsilon}$ closed?** I have quoted the part of the proof. The (7) referred to is as follows.

[image]

Comment: If there was a one-line explanation, he probably wouldn't have referred you to an exercise.

Comment: How are we supposed to understand this? What is (4)?

Comment: As it now seems likely that there is no simple answer to your question, have you considered asking the man himself, by posting a comment on his blog? (The point hasn't come up in any of the existing 32 comments on this entry.) I'm willing to ask him myself, but the privilege (if that's the word!) belongs to you, as the one who identified the problem. It shouldn't go unremarked, as your question is a reasonable one, which anyone might ask.

Comment: I've posted a [comment](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2016/09/27/246a-notes-2-complex-integration/#comment-474594) on Tao's blog, citing this question, and advocating a simplification of the proof along the lines suggested in my answer.

Comment: Dear Calum, thank you so much! (and sorry for the late reply.)

Answer (score 2):

By hypothesis, the function $\gamma': [a, b] \to \mathbb{C}$ is continuous, therefore $|\gamma'|: [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}_{\geqslant 0}, t \mapsto |\gamma'(t)|$ is continuous. Since $[a, b]$ is compact, $|\gamma'|$ is bounded above, say by $M \geqslant 0$.

At the start of the proof of Proposition 10, Tao obtains the upper bound
$$ \tag{3}\label{eq:ub}
|\gamma| \leqslant \int_a^b |\gamma'(t)|\,dt.
$$

If $a \leqslant T \leqslant T' \leqslant b$, then $\gamma_{[a, T']} = \gamma_{[a, T]} + \gamma_{[T, T']}$, therefore by the result of Exercise 7, and by \eqref{eq:ub},
$$
|\gamma_{[a, T']}| - |\gamma_{[a, T]}| = |\gamma_{[T, T']}| \leqslant \int_T^{T'} |\gamma'(t)|\,dt \leqslant M(T' - T).
$$

The left hand side of the claimed inequality (4) is therefore a (uniformly) continuous function of $T$. Rather more obviously, the right hand side of (4) is also a (uniformly) continuous function of $T$.

If we denote by $\Omega'_\epsilon$ the set of $T \in [a, b]$ such that (4) holds, then this is the inverse image of a closed set under a continuous function, and so is closed.

The set $\Omega_\epsilon$ is defined as the union of all intervals of the form $[a, T]$ contained in $\Omega'_\epsilon$, and so $\Omega_\epsilon$ is itself an interval: either it is the closed interval $[a, c]$, or it is the half-open interval $[a, c)$, where $c \in [a, b]$ is its least upper bound. In either case, $[a, c) \subseteq \Omega'_\epsilon$, therefore $c \in \Omega'_\epsilon$, because $\Omega'_\epsilon$ is closed. It follows that $[a, c] \subseteq \Omega'_\epsilon$, i.e. $c \in \Omega_\epsilon$, by the definition of $\Omega_\epsilon$. So $\Omega_\epsilon = [a, c]$.

It's hard to believe that this is what Tao had in mind, however, because if it were, it would mean that he throws away this strong information about $\Omega_\epsilon$, only to use the weaker fact that it is topologically closed. The rest of his argument *could* have been used to derive a contradiction from the hypothesis that $c < b$, and so to prove that $c = b$; but instead of doing this, Tao appeals to [the continuity method](http://www.tricki.org/article/Use_the_continuity_method), i.e. the principle that a non-empty open and closed subset of an interval of $\mathbb{R}$ is necessarily the whole interval. To set this up, he establishes in Exercise 9 that the interval $[a, b]$ is topologically connected. But the proof he suggests is along similar lines to the proof given here that $\Omega_\epsilon$ is closed:

> **Exercise 9** Let $a\leq b$ be real numbers. Show that the interval $[a, b]$ is topologically connected, that is to say the only two subsets of $[a, b]$ that are both open and closed relative to $[a, b]$ are the empty set and all of $[a, b]$. (*Hint:* if $E$ is a non-empty set that is both open and closed in $[a, b]$ and contains $a$, consider the supremum of all $T_* \in [a, b]$ such that $[a, T_*] \subset E$.)

I don't know why this redundancy has occurred, but most likely it's because of some silly mistake I've made. I offer the above proof, anyway, because at least it seems to establish that $\Omega_\epsilon$ is closed - even if it's at far too heavy a cost!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why Tao is going through all that to prove $\int_a^b|\gamma '| \le V_a^b(\gamma).$  I would do it this way:  First note that because $\gamma'$ is continuous on $[a,b],$ it is uniformly continuous there. So let $\epsilon>0.$ Choose $\delta > 0$ such that $|t-s| < \delta$ implies $|\gamma'(t)-\gamma'(s)| < \epsilon.$

Claim: If $a\le s<t \le b,$ with $t-s < \delta,$ then

$$\tag 1 \left | \,|\gamma(t) - \gamma(s)| - |\gamma'(t)|(t-s) \, \right | <\epsilon (t-s).$$

Proof: Using $||x|-|y|| \le |x-y|, $ we have the left side of  $(1)$ bounded above by

$$ | \gamma(t) - \gamma(s) - \gamma'(t)(t-s)| = \left | \int_s^t (\gamma'(u) - \gamma'(t))\,du \right| \le \int_s^t |\gamma'(u) - \gamma'(t)|\,du < \epsilon(t-s).$$

So now let $a=s_0 < s_1 < \cdots <s_n=b$ be a partition of $[a,b]$ with mesh size $<\delta.$ Then

$$ V_a^b(\gamma) \ge \sum_{k=1}^{n}|\gamma(s_k) - \gamma(s_{k-1})| = \sum_{k=1}^{n}|\gamma'(s_k)|(s_k - s_{k-1}) + \sum_{k=1}^{n}\left (|\gamma(s_k) - \gamma(s_{k-1})| - |\gamma'(s_k)|(s_k - s_{k-1})\right ).$$

In the last sum, the claim shows each summand, in absolute value, is less than $\epsilon(s_k-s_{k-1}).$ Thus this sum in absolute value is no more than $\epsilon(b-a).$ It follows that $$ V_a^b(\gamma) \ge  \sum_{k=1}^{n}|\gamma'(s_k)|(s_k - s_{k-1}) - \epsilon(b-a).$$ Now let the mesh size go to $0.$ We get $V_a^b(\gamma) \ge  \int_a^b|\gamma'| - \epsilon(b-a).$ Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, we have $V_a^b(\gamma) \ge  \int_a^b|\gamma'|$ as desired.